# Can we add a tag for Home Education?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

The number of families using home education with their kids is climbing but the issues one faces and answers to those issues can be slightly different so this tag would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a tag for that already, the [homeschooling](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homeschooling) tag.  I have suggested a synonym of [home-education](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/home-education) to make searching a little more intuitive.

Comment: I've just merged "homeschool" into "homeschooling" and "schooling" into "education".